# Return value: boolean vs int flag vs exception

Tags: java, api, sdk

I need to define a set of functions as part of an interface for a public facing SDK and trying to figure out the best way of signalling to the caller code if something was successful or not, and if not, why not.

My first consideration was return value vs exception. I think I need to use a combination of both for this one. Exceptions for erroneous states/errors caused by bugs. Return value to be used for times when function ran as expected and just want to return the result of the call to the caller.

Now, for return type. I could use ints (flags) or booleans. It has been argued internally that booleans should be used as it is simpler, and no need for flags. Booleans limit you to specifying success or failure, with no explanation.

I would make two arguments for using flags instead. First, you can return more than two possible values. Allowing for { success, fail, fail_reason_1, fail_reason_2, fail_reason_3 }. Note as this is an interface for implementations on various hardware devices it is probably desirable to be able to notify why an operation failed. e.g. the connected device doesn't support beep, has no LCD, doesn't support embedded crypto etc.

Who knows what the requirements will be in the future. Returning a bool locks you in now, whereas using flags allows you greater flexibility in the future. So what if you never need more than two values in the future. At least you have the option.

Considering this will be a public facing SDK I want as much flexibility so as to prevent breaking changes in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from success I only see multiple types of failures. Why can these not be wrapped in exceptions?

Comment: Enum or int flags. Same question remains. A failure could be semi expected. I.e. operation not supported. Exceptions change the flow and my understanding is should only be used for abnormal/unexpected states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the difference between returning a value to indicate the result of a method call and to throw an exception is that a value is just a notification about what happened. The method call should be considered as being performed successfully regarding the contract it defines. For example have a look how [boolean : Set.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is defined.

If a method throws an exception, this should indicate either an incorrect use of the method or a call while the object / whole system was in an illegal state. For example, trying to buy something for an user while his account does not have enough credits.

An exception is perfectly suited for capturing the different failure types: either by an exception hierarchy or by adding properties to the exception like `getFailureCode()` or combining them.

I would **not** use flags to indicate a failure condition in case the failure **must** be handled. Because ignoring return values is much to easy and can be missed by programmers, while exception have to be ignored actively.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it varies a lot based on your domain, clients, and the specifics of what you're providing. If you haven't already, you need to sit down with your clients and figure out how they're going to be using the library. Just off the top of my head, here are some things I'd be thinking about:

First, all the failure types you identified are basically the same thing - `UnsupportedOperationException`, with a reason why. Are there other failure types? If not, and you use exceptions, you possibly want one exception class with a type/cause/whatever as an enum property.

Second, it looks like many/most/all of your methods are going to have one or more failure types like this. Is that true? If so, does your API provide any way of determining what features a device supports? Consider this:

```
// Best if I probably don't care about the result if it's not SUCCESS
final Result result = myApiObject.someMethod();
if (result == Result.BEEP_UNSUPPORTED) {
....
} else if (result == Result.NO_DISPLAY) {
....
} else if ...
```

and this:

```
// Best if I have to handle every possible failure condition, and I care what
// the failure type is
try {
    myApiObject.someMethod();
} catch (final BeepUnsupportedException e) {
....
} catch (final NoDisplayException e) {
....
}
```

and this:

```
// Best if I have to consider every possible failure condition, but it probably
// doesn't matter what the failure type is
try {
    myApiObject.someMethod();
} catch (final MyApiException e) {
    if (Cause.BEEP_UNSUPPORTED == e.getCause()) {
        ....
    } else ....
```

and this:

```
// Best if I know in advance what features I may need
// someMethod() may still return response codes or throw an exception. In this case
// it's possibly OK to make it a RuntimeException, since clients are expected to
// poll for features.
if (myApiObject.supports(Feature.BEEP)
        && myApiObject.supports(Feature.DISPLAY)) {
    myApiObject.someMethod();
} else ...
```

Which of these is closest to the way your clients will want to use your system?

Third, how fatal are these errors? I totally agree with @Harmlezz that failures which must be handled need to be Exceptions. What neither of us can tell you without more information is whether your failures need to be handled or not. If clients will mostly be ignoring failures (they usually want the code to fail silently), or only mostly only care about `SUCCESS` or `!SUCCESS`, then return codes are probably okay. If failures *need* to be handled, then you should be throwing a checked exception. You probably want to stay away from unchecked exceptions, since these failures aren't programming errors and may be handled correctly by clients.